# Rad Studio XE8: "Run" button not enabled for iOS64 target

Tags: ios, delphi, ide, arm64, delphi-xe8

In Rad Studio XE8 for "iOS64 Device" target "Run" button not enabled (only "Run without Debugging" button is enabled). In Tools->Options->Debugger Options "iOS 64 Debugger for the 64-bit iOS Device" is present and highlighted for "iOS64 Device" target.
Does anybody faced this strange behaviour?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the [What's New in Delphi and C++Builder XE8](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/What's_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE8) documentation:

[Debugger Changes for XE8](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/What's_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE8#Debugger_Changes_for_XE8)

> **Debugging of iOS64 apps is not supported (F9 is not enabled when iOS Device 64-bit is the target platform).**
>  
>   Instead, you should set iOS Device 32-bit as the target platform, complete your debugging, and then rebuild your app for the iOS Device 64-bit target platform.

Comment: Thank you very much! Obviously, my searching in Embarcadero' documentation for something similar wasn't good enough....Rad Studio as always "the best"